# Git Update Changes not from Sub Module - ~/.vim - Pathogen

Tags: git, vim, pathogen

I was following the guide from here [John Anderson Vim Setup](http://sontek.net/turning-vim-into-a-modern-python-ide) to help setup vim. he steps through adding the various submodules to git in the format

```
git submodule add http://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive.git bundle/fugitive
```

since completing his guide I have made further changes. Getting ahead of myself I am on ubuntu my path is ~/.vim and I used the exact {autoload,bundle} setup as described in the guide.

I want to include the changes I added in my ~/.vimrc and the ohther bundles I have installed into my github so I can clone it and go on any other PC.

Really struggling to figure out how to get the changes in git. For example in my ~/.vim/bundle/ directory it has two new folders delimitMate and colorschemes. However when I do git push it returns everything as up to date.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are submodules, I figure. What you need to do, is:

```
# To add new modules
git add .gitmodules
git commit -m "Add new bundles"
# To add changes in vimrc
git add vimrc
git commit -m "Update my vimrc"
# To upload to Github
git push origin
```

On another PC, after cloning/pulling the Github repo, you need to:

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

To pull new changes to submodules you can later:

```
git submodule foreach git pull origin master
# NOTE: no trailing slash!
git add bundles/fugitive
git add bundles/etc
git commit -m "Update bundles"
git push
```

You can reduce the many `add`s by the following command:

```
git ls-files -m bundles | xargs git add
```

Comment: Thanks that worked well. Because my .vimrc is in ~/ and my git repo is in ~/.vim/.git I had to copy the file into the ~/.vim/ folder. There isn't anyway to add the ~/ other folder to the repo is there?

Comment: You can store your `vimrc` in the repo, and make a symlink in the $HOME, like `cd $HOME && ln -s .vim/vimrc .vimrc`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
git submodule update
git add delimitMate colorschemes [and any other file names]
git commit -m "My changes"
git push origin master
```

Pushing is for a remote repository.  Committing will commit to your local repo.  Changes must be committed locally first before you can push to a remote repository.